# Using JavaScript in my web app to delete files on the user's smart phone

Tags: javascript

I'm a software developer from Germany and I have a special problem concerning smart phones, websites and security!

My web application - which is optimized for smart phones - allowes it to upload photo files (made by the smart phone camera) up to our webserver.
(I use the regular HTML File Control.)

It works fine!

But now we think about possibilities to delete the uploaded photos on the smart phone - via the web app!

Is there any chance to realize that?

Our users work with Firefox 17.0 for Android.

Maybe Mozilla offers proprietary JavaScript code to get access to the local smart phone devices ... ?

Or is there any possibility to change the local security settings of Firefox Mobile?

If both solutions can't be realized, could I develop a smart phone app (which is locally installed) that deletes the photos on the phone? I'm sure I could!

But then I need a possibility to start the app using my website code.

So I have the same security problem - I think so ... again I need a way to "leave" my website to get access to local devices via JavaScript or something else (to start the installed app on the phone).

Is there anybody who has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: I sure hope that this is impossible using a default browser installation.

Comment: I think the only way to accomplish this is with a native app on the phone.  There are security measures that prevent altering anything but cookies and, with HTML 5, special types of databases on the user's device.  There are ways you can create desktop apps in Chrome that can write files using Chrome's new "Packaged Apps" feature.

Comment: There is no possible way to do that from the browser. BrowserVendors would be insane to enable such things.

Comment: "So I have the same security problem -" the security problem would be non secured photo uploading , not really wether the photo stays on the user's handset or not.

Comment: Maybe you can use the HTML5 Media Capture API. Then you don't have to delete the image files. Look at this introduction: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: As already stated, JavaScript runs in a sand boxed environment that prevents it from accessing the file system. Even the photo upload is done indirectly, as your application has no way of knowing the true path to the file on the user's device.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I think I have to choose another way, maybe an app or I will search after a filemanager app, so the user will be able to delete the the photos without my help. Does anybody know a good filemanager app for Android? Thanks. Thomas